# jquery howto: validate a div rather than a form

Tags: jquery, .net, validation

I'm using asp.net, so it already has a `<fomr id="aspnetForm" name="aspnetForm">`.

I want a page to allow "multiple form submit individually". For example I want the user to save their resume. On the "Education Experience" page, I want to allow multiple records of the user, each of the record can be edited and saved individually with ajax, but validated before ajax.

something like:

```
<form id="aspnetForm" name="aspnetForm">
<div class="item_edit">
    1
    <input type="text" class="required" name="title" />
    <input type="text" class="required" name="description" />
    <input type="button" class="save" value="save" />
</div>
<div class="item_edit">
    2
    <input type="text" class="required" name="title" />
    <input type="text" class="required" name="description" />
    <input type="button" class="save" value="save" />
</div>
</form>

$("input.save").click(function(){
    var thediv = $(this).parent();
    if(thediv.valid()){
        //save with ajax
    }
    else{
        //show error, modal window preferred
    }
})
```

btw: I'm using backbone.js, if helps.

EDIT: my code of backbone.js is like below. The above `<div class="item_edit">` was rendered from template.

```
APIPortfolio.Views.OtherInfoCollection = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : "#otherinfo-container",
    template : "#otherinfo-template",
    initialize : function(options) {
    this.modelList = options.modelList.models;
    },
    render : function() {
        var self = this;
    $(self.el).empty();
    _.each(this.modelList, function(model) {
            $(self.el).append(Mustache.to_html($(self.template).html(), model.toJSON()));
    })
    return this;
}
});
```

Comment: @run I want to validate the inputs/textarea/etc in the div asif they were in a form. I edited the post. more clear now?

Comment: hi, @Shyju. I think the problem itself has no relation to backbone.js. I just mentioned it to the reason that if backbone.js has an alternate solution/plugin, I'd like to accept. Do you know that?

Comment: Why don't you just use separate forms?

Comment: @BalusC the asp.net already has a form. I cannot nest other forms into that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery Validation? You can add attributes to you html elements and validate all of them via a single call.

Here's the link to it...seems like it will do the trick http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: yes, I'm using that. It applies well to a single form on page and only form elements. But I want to validate a div with event onclick. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you aren't using Backbone.js.  But if you decide to, you should have a view that represents your form, which associated with a model instance.  Within your view you should have an events property that handles your click event like so:

```
var Thingy = Backbone.Model.extend({
  //implement me
})

var ThingyForm = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: function(){
    'input.save click': function(){
      if(this.model.isValid()){
          this.model.save()
      }
      else{
          //show error, modal window preferred
      }
    }
  }
})

thingy = new Thingy({attr1: 'val1', attr2: 'val2'})
thingyForm = new ThingyForm({model: thingy})
```

There is plenty more to be done to wire this up to a remote resource and to wire up the validation of the model, etc.  But this should get you started.  May I suggest the following two resources:

[Backbone.js Documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) - comprehensive, Backbone is very lightweight, you can read the entire source code in an hour probably.

[Backbone Fundamentals free eBook](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals) - the first four or five chapters of that book will get you started.

Good luck.

Comment: I edited the post and append my backbone.js code. Do you suggest that I add `event` to the code and forget validating things on page. All validation should be done in Backbone.Model?

Comment: if the form is associated (logically) with a resource that is represented as backbone model, then yes, the validation should occur in the backbone model, and the DOM updates that are triggered by a validation failure should be triggered via the form Backbone view (assuming one exists) that represents the form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you may have more types of form elements in your 'item_edit' div, you could add a class to each of the form elements in your div and call it maybe 'item'. So the 'item_div' would now look like:

```
<div class="item_edit">
    1
    <input type="text" class="required item" name="title" />
    <input type="text" class="required item" name="description" />
    <input type="button" class="save" value="save" />
</div>
```

We are doing this so that we do not assume that there s only a 'title' and a 'description' inside 'item_edit'

You could define a function that saves partial elements of the form in this fashion:

```
function savePartial(itemEditDiv)
{
    var bool = true;
    $(itemEditDiv).find('item').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val()    //this is the value of the 'title' or 'description' etc
        //code to check if the value is valid (set bool = false in case its not valid)
    });
    return bool;
}
```

Now all you need to do is add a click event handler to the 'save' buttons to call this savePartial function:

```
$("input.save").click(function(){
    var thediv = $(this).parent();
    if(savePartial(thediv))
    {
         //success message
    }
    else
    {
        //something went wrong
    }
});
```

Additionally you could add a 'msg' parameter to your 'item' fields and capture messages of invalid items in an array to display error messages.

Comment: My problem is mainly about `//code to check if the value is valid`. I want a validation plugin. But the plugins I found were all designed for `<form>`.